How do I pass a varchar to a tvf and use that parameter to query for the results SQL Server
I'm using a TVF to return a list of recordID's based on the deparment code of the primary project manager.  The department code can include alpha and numeric characters so it's defined as a varchar.
This is my current TVF.
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[searchDeptCode](@inDeptCode varchar)
RETURNS @recordID TABLE 
(recordID int NOT NULL)
AS
BEGIN
    
    if (@inDeptCode IS NULL)
        INSERT INTO @recordID
            SELECT DISTINCT recordID
            FROM projectRecord ORDER BY recordID

    if (@inDeptCode IS NOT NULL)
        INSERT INTO @recordID
            SELECT DISTINCT recordID
            FROM projectRecord 
            WHERE dbo.getPersonDeptCode(dbo.getPersonID(recordID)) like '%' + @inDeptCode + '%'
            ORDER BY recordID
    RETURN
    
END

GO

This is how I'm calling it where 54390 is the department code.
select * from searchDeptCode('54390')

It should return 2 recordID's but it's returning nearly all of the records in the table.  When I run the select statement independently, it returns the correct 2 records.
I'm sure I'm missing something simple but can't put my finger on it.

It looks fine but what does dbo.getPersonDeptCode(dbo.getPersonID(recordID)) do? Maybe that is the culprit and returning true no matter what the @inDeptCode is - provided you have a length for varchar.

You should always (no exceptions) provide a length to your varchar parameters, variables or columns - otherwise, like in the case of a parameter, you might be confronted with the default length of 1 character .....
Try this:
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[searchDeptCode](@inDeptCode VARCHAR(50))

and adapt the (50) length to whatever length makes sense in your case.
Also see: Bad habits to kick: declaring VARCHAR without (length) for more background and info

Thanks, I knew it was something simple (and stupid on my part).
Works fine now.
